# Xamarin Visual Studio not recognizing images

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin to develop an Android app in C# using Visual Studio 2012.  It's been going fairly well so far but I'm having a problem with designing the interface.  I put some images in Resources/drawable for the project, but I can't get the solution explorer in VS to pick up that these images are there.  It only shows the default Icon.png file that is included in every new project.  I was briefly able to get it to detect one other image by cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but that hasn't worked since, and even in that case I couldn't get it to actually display in an ImageView.  I'm unable to point my ImageView to any of my images since VS isn't creating a reference for them to use (e.g. @drawable/myimage).  Refreshing the solution explorer does nothing.  Anyone have any other ideas on what I could try?

Comment: Check if you do not have any special characters like '-' in the file name of your image.

Comment: is the build action of the image set to `AndroidResource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right clicking the folder in solution explorer, selecting add > existing file, selecting the file, and then rebuilding the project solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the .imagetype portion

like: **image.png** will be replace by **image**

its work for me